# How to prevent others from hotlinking to my images on Blogger.com?

Tags: security, blogger, images

I have a `Blogger.com` website that another site is hotlinking to various images. I don't believe I have access to the *htaccess* file to try and stop it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Your images aren't stored on Blogger.com, they're most likely in Picasa-web-albums / Google+ photos if you uploaded them via the Blogger post editor.

There is absolutely no way to stop people hot-linking to them.

Try watermarking them, so you at least get some credit when they're used.